# relative motion between particles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, dynamical-systems, analytic-geometry

Consider three vehicles A, B and C moving with non-zero constant speeds and varying angular rotation rates. We know that, with respect to the frame attached to vehicle A, B moves in a straight line path (either approaching or receding). Similarly, with respect to the frame attached to vehicle B, C moves in a straight line path (again, either approaching or receding).

Does this imply that from vehicle A's frame of reference, vehicle C also moves in a straight line path? (This line could be different from the straight line connecting A and B.)

Comment: Try constructing nontrivial examples. What happens? Add your work to the question text above.

Comment: If I read this correctly, the distance between vehicles does not necessarily increase at a constant rate, rather, their speeds in some other frame of reference are constant.

Comment: Given that its only their tangential speeds (in a Frenet-Serret framework) which are constant, I would say it that indeed the distance between vehicles does not necessarily increase at a constant rate.